# Error on progressDialog and Toast with custom recyclerview adapter file

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need help for showing toast and progress dialog inside volley request, and I use a custom adapter file when click on the card will send data with volley, please give better flow or fixing this code.

this is my onBindViewHolder inside adapter file

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final DataPicking task = taskList.get(position);
        holder.numberid.setText(task.getNomorid());
        holder.nama.setText(task.getNamakonsumen());
        holder.rate.setText(task.getRate());
        holder.tanggal.setText(task.getTanggal());
        holder.salesman.setText(task.getSalesman());

        holder.cardList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                .setTitle("Proses Picking")
                .setMessage("Apakah kamu yakin ingin memproses picking data ini?")
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        String nomorid = taskList.get(position).getNomorid();
                        PickingActivity picking = new PickingActivity();
                        picking.kirimData(nomorid);               
                    }})
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is kirimData function for send data with volley

```
public void kirimData(final String nomorid){

        // Log.e("ini kirimdata ",nomorid);
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.URL_SET_PICKING, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Picking Response: " + response.toString());
                //hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.e(TAG, "obj: " + jObj.toString());
                    String error = jObj.getString("status");
                    Log.e(TAG, "obj: " + error);
                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (error.equals("1")) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                /*Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();*/
                Log.e(TAG, "Proses Picking Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Proses Picking Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("nomorid", nomorid);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

    }
```

and this is the error log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ProgressDialog.setMessage(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.sip.gotrack.PickingActivity.kirimData(PickingActivity.java:167)
        at com.sip.gotrack.PickingAdapter$1$1.onClick(PickingAdapter.java:69)
```

please help me for this error

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `pDialog` being initialized?

Inside kirimData, initialize pDialog like this in the beginning.

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
```

It seems pDialog is not initialized before this method is called.

Comment: i do in oncreate 

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
pDialog.setCancelable(false);

Comment: Ok, I got it. The way you are calling kirimData (in onClick) is problematic . You are initializing a new instance of PickingActivity and then firing kirimData via this instance. This is the wrong way of doing because in this, onCreate of the above instance does not get called because of which pProgress does not initialized.

Comment: If you want to call kirimData, you first need to pass the nomorid via an interface back to the Activity (I think it is PickingActivity ). Then in the implementation of the interface, you will call kirimData method)

Comment: can u give me example for pass the nomorid and execute kirimData when onclick in adapter